# Using Roboto thin or condensed

Tags: android, android-fonts

Is it possible to use [Roboto thin or condensed style](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/design/Roboto_Specimen_Book_20111129.pdf) in ICS without having to include the .ttf and load it manually, I mean **without** using:

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/DroidSerif-Bold.ttf");
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Versions of Android older than 4.1 include just four basic styles of Roboto: Regular, **Bold**, *Italic* and ***BoldItalic***. There is no way to use thin or condensed styles in ICS without assets.

Android 4.1 ([JellyBean, API16](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)) and up [includes several more Roboto styles](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Fonts):

- Regular
- Italic
- Bold
- Bold-italic
- Light
- Light-italic
- Condensed regular
- Condensed italic
- Condensed bold
- Condensed bold-italic

Comment: Do you know why this is so? A link somewhere with more details maybe?
Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: I just corrected the answer because it's possible to use them in Android 4.1 and up.