# How to use Roboto in xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, roboto

I hear it often nowadays: “Roboto is the default font type”. But how do I use this default font type? What I mean specifically is that in the old days when I used to download the assets, etc., I used to have to specify things like

```
<item name="typeface">roboto_bold</item>
```

Imagine I am interested in using all of say (in turn)

```
roboto_thin
 roboto_thin_italic
 roboto_light
 roboto_light_italic
 roboto_regular
 roboto_italic
 roboto_medium
 roboto_medium_italic
 roboto_bold
 roboto_bold_italic
 roboto_black
 roboto_black_italic
 roboto_condensed_light
 roboto_condensed_light_italic
 roboto_condensed_regular
 roboto_condensed_italic
 roboto_condensed_bold
 roboto_condensed_bold_italic
 roboto_slab_thin
 roboto_slab_light
 roboto_slab_regular
 roboto_slab_bold
```

How do I specify them in my xml layout file or `style.xml` file?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I've already found some possibilities

#### Using `fontfamily`

The simplest way would be add `fontFamily` attribute to your specific `view` like `TextView`

According to [How to change fontFamily of TextView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android)

> From android 4.1 / 4.2 / 5.0, the following
>   [Roboto](http://robotofont.com/) font families are available:
>
> ```
> android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular
> android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
> android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed
> android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"      // roboto thin (android 4.2)
> android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"    // roboto medium (android 5.0)
> ```
>
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:typeface
>
> in combination with
>
> ```
> android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
> ```
>
> this 14 variants are possible:
>
> - Roboto regular
> - Roboto italic
> - Roboto bold
> - Roboto bold italic
> - Roboto-Light
> - Roboto-Light italic
> - Roboto-Thin
> - Roboto-Thin italic
> - Roboto-Condensed
> - Roboto-Condensed italic
> - Roboto-Condensed bold
> - Roboto-Condensed bold italic
> - Roboto-Medium
> - Roboto-Medium italic

You can also do this programmatically using code as below:

```
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-thin", Typeface.NORMAL));
```

#### Using `typeface`

Available built-ibn fonts are:

- normal
- sans
- serif
- monospace

You can cobine them like below:

```
   android:typeface="sans" | "serif" | "monospace"
```

See [android:typeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:typeface).

#### Using `styles.xml`

You set style in styles.xml` like that:

```
<style name="boldText">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

and to use this style in `main.xml` layout file just use:

```
style="@style/boldText"
```

#### Combining Text atrributes

You can mix `TextView` attributes like in code below:

```
 android:fontFamily="serif" 
 android:textStyle="italic"
```

#### Using third-party libraries

[`Foundry`](https://bitbucket.org/josephearl/foundry/overview) -  apply custom typefaces through XML layouts and styles.

[`android-typeface-helper`](https://github.com/norbsoft/android-typeface-helper) - Typeface helper for Android

#### Additional lecture

You may also want to read about [`Roboto`](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto) typeface and [Typography](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html) Google's Design Guide.

Similar StackOverflow Issues:

- [Using Roboto thin or condensed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485902/using-roboto-thin-or-condensed)
- [How do I specify eg. Roboto-Medium or Roboto-Black in styles.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023304/how-do-i-specify-eg-roboto-medium-or-roboto-black-in-styles-xml)
- [Use Roboto font in app with minimum API level 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631326/use-roboto-font-in-app-with-minimum-api-level-14)

  Hope it help

Comment: Even I use this, on Samsung the font looks different. I noticed the difference with dollar sign. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [piotrek's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4730812/piotrek1543) answer, here is a quick cheatsheet if you haven't decided which Roboto font to use:

[image]

Comment: Where can we download these fonts?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky https://fonts.google.com/?query=roboto